# WHERE clause with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check a value inside a WHERE clause.

How can I turn this pseudo into real SQL code?

```sql
declare @includeReserved int = 0 -- can be 0, 1 or 2

select *
from Tickets
where
(
    -- if @includeReserved = 0:
    ticketIsReserved = 0
    -- else if @includeReserved = 1:
    ticketIsReserved = 0 or ticketIsReserved = 1
    -- else if @includeReserved = 2:
    ticketIsReserved = 1
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `and` and `or`:

```
where (@includeReserved = 0 and ticketIsReserved = 0) or
      (@includeReserved = 1 and ticketIsReserved in (0, 1)) or             
      (@includeReserved = 2 and ticketIsReserved = 1)
```

You might want to include:

```
or @includeReserved not in (0, 1, 2)
```

If you want other values to not filter at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try with case conditions...

```
declare @includeReserved int = 0 -- can be 0, 1 or 2

select *
from Tickets
where
case when (@includeReserved = 0 and ticketIsReserved = 0) then 1
     when (@includeReserved = 1 and (ticketIsReserved = 0 or ticketIsReserved = 1)) then 1 
     when (@includeReserved = 2 and ticketIsReserved = 1) then  end = 1
```

Comment: Why? In a `WHERE` clause you can simply use `AND` and `OR` as shown in all the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND` and `OR`:

```
select *
from Tickets
where
(
  (@includeReserved = 0 and ticketIsReserved = 0)
  or    
  (@includeReserved = 1 and ticketIsReserved in (0,1))
  or
  (@includeReserved = 2 and ticketIsReserved = 1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want this logic:

```
select *
from Tickets
where
    (@includeReserved = 0 and ticketIsReserved = 0) or
    (@includeReserved = 1 and ticketIsReserved in (0, 1)) or
    (@includeReserved = 2 and ticketIsReserved = 1);
```